# VirtualBox - Trouble with Windows host and Linux raw disk guest

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows, virtualbox

I am having some trouble creating a bootable Linux raw disk.

I have two storage devices:

[image]

Here is a breakdown of disk 1:

[image]

Here is the output from `.\VBoxManage internalcommands listpartitions -rawdisk \\.\PhysicalDrive1`:

[image]

To summarize, I have both Windows 10 and Ubuntu installed on disk 1. I should note that I have disabled Intel Rapid Storage Technology and am using AHCI in order to support Ubuntu 20.04.1 (its kernel, that is).

My goal is to create a `vmdk` stored on disk 0 (`D:`) of a raw disk pointing towards my Ubuntu installation, on disk 1 (partitions 5, 6, and 7). I do not want to remove the ability to dual-boot my PC directly into Ubuntu, but would like to be able to access the Ubuntu instance from Windows.

Here are my steps:

1. Create the raw `vmdk`.

```
.\VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename "D:\Virtual Machines\Ubuntu Raw Disk\ubuntu-rawdisk.vmdk" -rawdisk \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1 -partitions 5 -relative
```

[image]

2. Create a new VM.

   a. Add `D:\Virtual Machines\Ubuntu Raw Disk\ubuntu-rawdisk.vmdk` as an AHCI SATA controller.

   b. Modify the boot order so that "Hard Disk" is first and disable everything else.

   c. Enable `EFI`.
3. Boot.

This does not work. It boots into the UEFI Interactive Shell.

[image]

So, I enter `exit` to go to the setup tool. I go to "Boot Manager" and attempt to boot from the harddisk (`UEFI VBOX HARDDISK VB273df1fa-e2d31765`).

At this point, I am completely stuck. It seems like an `EFI` problem. I have tried creating the raw disk with partitions 5, 6, and 7. No change. I have tried creating the raw disk with partitions 2 and 5, but this fails. I have tried accessing `fs0:` on the shell, but this fails.

I also tried creating the raw `vmdk` from the entire disk. and enabling Host I/O Cache. This worked. I would rather not do this because if I accidentally boot into Windows, well... you know.

I should mention that, while I am familiar with Linux in a command-line sense, I am not familiar with how bootloaders work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A few things... Raw disk access requires you to run VBox as Admin (maybe you already do). Linux needs parts 5,6 and 7, so add them. You need to give your VM an EFI part, maybe part 2 for you... in my case I created a small virtual disk with a UEFI partition because there was *something* I wanted/needed to do differently in VBox vs. Bare Metal (don't ask what... it's been a while). Finally, because I don't use GUIDs for partitions, I put my raw disk vmdk in the same position on the VM as the physical disk in my system (/dev/sdc, in my case) ...using another empty virtual disk as a place holder.

Comment: Yes, I am running as admin. Partition 2 does have GRUB and Windows Boot Loader on it, but VirtualBox will not create a raw vmdk if partition 2 is included.

Comment: ...maybe that's the *something* I needed to do differently (because Windows was being a butt about allowing access to it) :) Anyway, to get Grub on my virtual disk EFI partition, I added it to a different VM and mounted/installed it from there. ...again, it's been a while.